# Prove a Picard map is a contraction map in a specific complete metric space

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

Define a complete function space with a metric:$$\begin{align*}
C_M=\{\phi:\mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R}^n  \text{ continuous and the norm is } \|y\|_M= \sup_{t\ge 0} \frac{|y(t)|}{e^{Mt} } \}
\end{align*}$$ where $|\cdot|$ is euclidean norm in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $\mathbb R_+=[0,\infty)$, and $M$ is a positive consitant.
Also, define a function $$\begin{align*}
f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n
\end{align*}$$ with global Lipschitz condition, that is $$\begin{align*}
|f(x)-f(y)|&\le L|x-y| & \forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n
\end{align*}$$ Then, I define a function $$\begin{align*}
J(y)&=v+ \int_0^t f(y(s)) \ ds
\end{align*}$$ where $y\in C_M$ and $v$ is a fixed vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ .
The question asks under what condition the map $J$ is a contraction. That is I'm supposed to show $$\begin{align*}
\|J(y_1)-J(y_2)\|_M &\le k \|y_1-y_2\|_M
\end{align*}$$ where $0\le k<1$

However, when I do this, I encountered some problems. This is my attempt:

It's clear that $U$ is a function from $C_M \to C_M$, then $$\begin{align*}
\|J(y_1)-J(y_2)\|_M &\le \int_0^t \|f(y_1)-f(y_2)\| \ ds \\ &= \int_0^t \sup_{*} \frac{|f(y_1)-f(y_2)|}{e^{Ms}}   \ ds &(1) \\ &\le  L\int_0^t \sup_{*} \frac{|y_1-y_2|}{e^{Ms}} \ ds &(2)
\end{align*}$$This is a function changing the upper limit.
My questions are

1. What  $*$ should be the in $(1)$ ? Is it $s\ge 0$ ,  $t\ge s\ge 0$ , or other else?
2. My 3rd line is due to the global Lipschitz condition by $f$ , but how should I deal with the integration in $(2)$ ? $y_1,y_2$ are fucntions with respect to $s$ , should I integrate them?
   Any help on this problem? Thanks

Comment: $M=2L$ gives contraction factor $1/2$, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2205447/inequality-in-the-proof-of-unique-solution-of-an-ode, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/837792/an-application-of-banach-fixed-point-theorem-for-initial-value-problem, and a little more generally https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2987629/understanding-the-motivation-for-the-answer-in-generalizing-odes-to-banach-space